# Replace line with command sed

Tags: bash, sed, replace

I want to replace a line in a file, but I'm kinda lost with the command line.

Here's the specific line I want to change; line 55 of a PHP file:

> $response['data']['responseData']['ballonsftver'] =
>   @constant('BALLON_VER');

I want to replace for this:

> $response['data']['responseData']['ballonsftver'] = "2.1-0";

How do I use `sed` to replace that line?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will replace  `@constant('BALLON_VER')` on line 55 with `"2.1-0"`

```
sed -i 55s/"@constant('BALLON_VER')"/"\"2.1-0\""/ filename
```

Careful while using -i switch of sed to perform an in-place editing.

Comment: Thank you! It worked like a charm. I was also forgetting the "\" in order to ignore the quotes.